# Error when assigning value in 2D array

Tags: c

```
double** Make2DDoubleArray(int arraySizeX, int arraySizeY) {
    double** theArray;
    theArray = (double**) malloc(arraySizeX*sizeof(double*));
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySizeX; i++)
    {
        theArray[i] = &(malloc(arraySizeY*sizeof(double)));
        memset(&(theArray[i]), 0, arraySizeY*sizeof(double));
    }
    return theArray;
}
```

I need to make a 2D array with `malloc` in C. I used the above method.

When I access the returned array (let’s call it `Matrix`) with `Matrix[1,2] = 2.0;` it throws an error:

> cannot convert ‘double’ to ‘double*’ in assignment

But I don't see why `Matrix[1,2]` is a pointer and not a value?
`Matrix` is a pointer of pointers, and `Matrix[i]` is a pointer to a list of `double`s, so `Matrix[i,j]` should be a `double` and not a `double *`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Matrix[i, j]` is the item in `Matrix` at the index `i, j`, which is the result of the comma operator on the values `i` and `j`, which is just `Matrix[j]`. You probably mean `Matrix[i][j]`.

In addition to that:

- Don’t cast the return value of `malloc`:

  ```
  double** theArray = malloc(arraySizeX * sizeof(double));
  ```
- You are using the wrong `sizeof`; it’s `sizeof(double*)`:

  ```
  double** theArray = malloc(arraySizeX * sizeof(double*));
  ```
- This makes no sense; drop the `&`:

  ```
  theArray[i] = &(malloc(arraySizeY*sizeof(double)));
  ```
- This is wrong; drop the `&` again:

  ```
  memset(&(theArray[i]), 0, arraySizeY*sizeof(double));
  ```

Answer (score 2):

These lines are wrong:

```
theArray[i] = &(malloc(arraySizeY*sizeof(double)));
memset(&(theArray[i]), 0, arraySizeY*sizeof(double));
```

I am surprised the compiler didn't complain about taking the address of a temporary in the first call.

You need:

```
theArray[i] = malloc(arraySizeY*sizeof(double));
           // ^^ Drop the &
memset(theArray[i], 0, arraySizeY*sizeof(double));
    // ^^ Drop the &
```